# sp_who returns more rows than the value of "max degree of parallelism"

Tags: sql-server, parallelism

`sp_configure` returns the following values on a server.

```
name                      minimum   maximum config_value    run_value
max degree of parallelism       0     32767            8    8
```

However, `sp_who1` and `sp_WhoIsActive` show that some *spids* have more than 8 rows (like 18 or so). Shouldn't it be at most 8 rows in this case?

This query returns a lot of rows from time to time:

```
SELECT * 
FROM sys.sysprocesses sp
where exists 
(
    select spid 
    from sys.sysprocesses 
    where spid =sp.spid 
    and sp.waitresource = ''
    group by spid 
    having count(*)>9
)
```

Comment: There's a chance that portions of the execution plan are going parallel and waiting for a different portion of the plan to finish doing what its doing (also parallel).  Can you post an execution plan of a spid that you are seeing exhibit this behavior?

Answer (score 10):

> Shouldn't it be at most 8 rows in this case?

No, because a single execution plan can use more *threads* than specified by the effective degree of parallelism (DOP).

Only a maximum of DOP threads will be active on a *scheduler* at a given moment in time. SQL Server (2005 onward) limits a parallel query to DOP schedulers, not DOP threads.

Since a scheduler abstracts a logical processor, this effectively limits the parallelism as desired.

DOP threads are assigned to each parallel branch, where a branch is delimited by Parallelism (exchange) operators.

For more information, see my Simple Talk article:

[Understanding and Using Parallelism in SQL Server](https://www.simple-talk.com/sql/learn-sql-server/understanding-and-using-parallelism-in-sql-server/)

and/or my PASS Summit 2013 session recording:

[Parallel Query Execution](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=yzW5cqI0uZs)